# How to copy over material settings to another material assigned to object faces?

Tags: python, materials, scripting, add-on

I'm working with a complicated scenario that requires me to programmatically swap multiple materials in and out of an object at a time. This object has multiple materials applied to different faces of the object. These materials are blank "hosts" and are only meant to represent the faces of the object that the swap-able materials should be applied to.

The goal with this system is to copy over the settings of the swap-able materials into the blank "host" materials.

I'm not very familiar with Blender's material system portion of the API, so there might be an easier way to do this, but would it be possible to copy over the settings listed [here](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Material.html) to the "host" materials? Most importantly the Node Tree?

Apologies I don't have any example code, I'm really stumped here and don't even know where to begin.

Comment: "hosts" = placeholders? So basically you want to have a mapping (a dictionary in Python) that translates a placeholder into the final material? You don't have to copy settings between materials, you can assign a material slot to a new material. You can make a copy of the material before assignment. If you have a lot of users of the placeholder material, it may make sense to modify the placeholder material to become the final material, but in most cases just iterating over all objects and all material slots will be easier.

Comment: But first, prepare some example of your problem, because it's hard to help otherwise.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady Ok wow, thank you for the info, this is very helpful, so your saying that the faces are stored assigned to a material slot, not the material itself? I didn't know that's how that worked, this one here right? https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.MaterialSlot.html

I'll work on getting an example and edit it into the question.

Comment: Yes, each face has a slot index property. Then the `bpy.types.Mesh` holds a list of materials, where the first material (index 0) defines the material for faces with slot index = 0, and so on. Sometimes an object wrapper can be used to store this list of materials instead: https://i.imgur.com/AIJIafz.png .

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was able to find a solution to this with the help of @Markus von Broady, thank you for the information btw!

The setup for a blender file is quite easy:

1. Create a new Blender file
2. Clear the scene
3. Add 3 spheres to the scene
4. Combine the 3 spheres into one object by selecting them all and using `CTRL + j`
5. Tab into edit mode
6. Select the mesh of the left most sphere
7. Create a new material slot under "Materials", then click the "Assign" button
   8 Repeat step 7 for the 2 other spheres
8. Add 3 materials to the scene; 'Red', 'Green', 'Blue'

Here is the code, this can be run as a script in the Blender text editor:

```
import bpy
import bmesh

import os
import random

# Left sphere = [1024, 1535] = placeholder #1
# Middle sphere = [0, 511] = placeholder #2
# Right Sphere = [512, 1023] = placeholder #3

export_path = r"C:\Users\torri\Desktop"

materials = ["Blue", "Red", "Green"]

spheres = [
    0,  # Left sphere
    1,  # Middle sphere
    2,  # Right sphere
]


def uniquify(path):
    filename, extension = os.path.splitext(path)
    counter = 1

    while os.path.exists(path):
        path = filename + " (" + str(counter) + ")" + extension
        counter += 1

    return path


export_path = uniquify(os.path.join(export_path, "test_model.glb"))


def set_mat_faces(material, sphere):
    invisible_material = bpy.data.materials["INVISIBLE"]
    object = "Sphere"

    material = bpy.data.materials[material]

    sphere_mat_slot = sphere

    # Get target object as active object, obj
    bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = bpy.data.objects[object]  # Setting head object as active
    obj = bpy.context.active_object

    # apply material to sphere_mat_slot
    obj.data.materials[sphere_mat_slot] = material

    # Make all other spheres invisible
    for i in spheres:
        if i != sphere:
            obj.data.materials[i] = invisible_material

    bpy.ops.export_scene.gltf(
        filepath=export_path,
        check_existing=True,
        export_format='GLB',
    )

    # Reset materials to default

    for i in spheres:
        obj.data.materials[i] = None


set_mat_faces(random.choice(materials), random.choice(spheres))
```

The last little bits of the `set_mat_faces` function just export the scene as a .glb 3D model.

You can also find the example file I used here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rOCznztXsbA2R_Ln44l0a6rt1Pl9UnwJ/view?usp=sharing